# requests post throws error raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

Tags: python, json

I'm at a loss here, this is the python :

```
jsonrpc_req = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/listCompetitions", "params": {"filter":{ "eventTypeIds" : [1]  }}, "id": 1}'

print(json.dumps(json.loads(jsonrpc_req), indent=3))

print(" ")

response = requests.post(url, data=jsonrpc_req, headers=headers)

print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), indent=3))
```

and it throws this :  `raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Which I am assuming means that there is something wrong with jsonrpc_req

however the output from the json.dumps looks ok :

```
{
   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/listCompetitions",
   "params": {
      "filter": {
         "eventTypeIds": [
            1
         ]
      }
   },
   "id": 1
}
```

The server response was also 410.

I don't understand how it can be getting None

Comment: Where is that error coming? Are you sure it isn't on the *response*?

Comment: HTTP code 410 means *Gone*. The required resource no longer exists. The response text is likely to be empty and you try to decode either `None` or an empty string...

Comment: Thank you, this is my inexperience with this area